# WPF DataGrid different controls in the same column - incorrect binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am developing the application which performs checks on the list of items. Each item has the list of the checks that need to be performed on it. Each check can be one of 3 types: CheckBox, ComboBox, TextBox.

I would like to have Datagrid with 2 columns (one for item name, second for list of checks). Second column contains another DataGrid with 2 columns (one for check name, second for check control). The purpose is to have different types of controls in the same column bound with the Check models.

The problem is that **binding with CheckValue doesn't work**, however bindings with all the other properties work fine.

The last column contains CheckBoxes, TextBox and ComboBox, however they are not filled with any values.
Does anyone know what is wrong with below code?

Here are examples of model classes

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Check> Checks { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
        Checks = new ObservableCollection<Check>();
    }
}

public enum CheckType
{
    CheckBox,
    ComboBox,
    TextBox
}

public abstract class Check
{        
    public string CheckName { get; set; }
    public CheckType CheckType { get; protected set; }
    public abstract object CheckValue { get; set; }
}

public class CheckBox : Check
{
    private bool checkValue;

    public CheckBox()
    {
        CheckType = CheckType.CheckBox;
    }

    public override object CheckValue
    {
        get
        {
            return checkValue;
        }
        set
        {
            checkValue = (bool)value;
        }
    }
}

public class ComboBox : Check
{
    private List<string> checkValue;

    public ComboBox()
    {
        CheckType = CheckType.ComboBox;
    }

    public override object CheckValue
    {
        get
        {
            return checkValue;
        }
        set
        {
            checkValue = value as List<string>;
        }
    }
}

public class TextBox : Check
{
    private string checkValue;

    public TextBox()
    {
        CheckType = CheckType.TextBox;
    }

    public override object CheckValue
    {
        get
        {
            return checkValue;
        }
        set
        {
            checkValue = value as string;
        }
    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        Item item = new Item();
        item.ItemName = "First item";

        Check check1 = new CheckBox() { CheckName = "Check 1", CheckValue = true };
        Check check2 = new CheckBox() { CheckName = "Check 2", CheckValue = false };
        Check text1 = new TextBox() { CheckName = "Check 3", CheckValue = "Please enter check" };
        Check combo1 = new ComboBox() { CheckName = "Check 4", CheckValue = new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2" } };

        item.Checks.Add(check1);
        item.Checks.Add(check2);
        item.Checks.Add(text1);
        item.Checks.Add(combo1);

        Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

And finally here is XAML code of the main window.

```
<Window x:Class="ItemTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:ItemTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="mainViewModel"/>         
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource mainViewModel}}">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item" Binding="{Binding ItemName}" /> 
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Checks">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Checks}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CheckName}" />
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ContentControl>
                                                <ContentControl.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CheckType}" Value="CheckBox">
                                                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckValue}"/>
                                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CheckType}" Value="ComboBox">
                                                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CheckValue}" />
                                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CheckType}" Value="TextBox">
                                                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding CheckValue}" />
                                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </ContentControl.Style>
                                            </ContentControl>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the ItemControl's Content property:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
```

WPF will automatically set DataTemplate's DataContext to its parent ContentControl's Content. But in your XAML you don't set the Content property (you only specify ContentControl's Style, but forget to set its Content).

And don't forget to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on your control bindings, otherwise you may see no updates in your viewmodel.

Comment: Great answer! It finally does work :-) Thank you nightcoder, I spent so much time today to solve it.

Comment: @JacekT, you are welcome :) And yeah, what I don't like in WPF is that if you don't have much experience with it, you may waste much time trying to make it work as expected. Unfortunately, some (many?) things don't seem obvious.

Answer (score 0):

XAML example working, with binding for BindingList :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridParametros"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="5"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        HeadersVisibility="All"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        RowHeaderWidth="20"
        SelectionUnit="FullRow"
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
        CanUserAddRows="false"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        FontFamily="Arial" 
        CellEditEnding="dataGridParametros_CellEditEnding" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IdParametro}" Header="Id" FontFamily="Arial" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Codigo}" Header="Código" FontFamily="Arial" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Binding="{Binding Mnemonico}" Header="Mnemonico" FontFamily="Arial" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="250*" Binding="{Binding Descricao}" Header="Descrição" FontFamily="Arial" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Valor" Width="150">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TipoCampo}" Value="CheckBox">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Valor , Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TipoCampo}" Value="ComboBox">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Valor , Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TipoCampo}" Value="TextBox">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Valor , Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentControl.Style>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```